# Input Range Slider functions

Tags: php, jquery, slider

It is possible with an input range slider to call functions?

Example: A range slider with 4 value ( 0 - max 4).
If the slider is on value 2 call a jQuery script.

Possible?

Comment: Why not just catch the change() event?  http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible call function if your are using jquery range slider when you stop sliding there

```
Code examples:
Initialize the slider with the stop callback specified:

$( ".selector" ).slider({
  stop: function( event, ui ) {}
});

//Bind an event listener to the slidestop event:


$( ".selector" ).on( "slidestop", function( event, ui ) {} );

//event in stop event in jquery.
```

Comment: Hmm. Sorry, sounds interesting - but how can I with the code above?

Answer (score 0):

here is your code you can  use this.

```
  $("#div-slider").change(function(event, ui) {
        // set the current value to whatever is selected.
             current = ui.value;
             if(current == 2){
                 $('#logo').hide("fast"); 
               }else{
                    $('#logo').show("fast");
                 }
  });
```

Comment: Hmm. It does not work. But let me buy you a coffee for ur try. Paypal?

Answer (score 0):

OK. It works. Here is the code:

```
 $("#div-slider").change(function(event, ui) {
    // set the current value to whatever is selected.
         current =   document.getElementById("slider-1").value; 
         if(current == 2){
             $('#logo').hide("fast"); 
           }else{
                $('#logo').show("fast");
             }
```

});

@Gaurav: A tip for your work.